# In Quill, how to parse deltas and replace some of its content

Tags: javascript, parsing, emoji, quill, rich-text-editor

After experimenting a lot with `contenteditable` elements, I finally chosed [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) to create a rich text message box on a chat app, because it is correctly handling selection, which appears to be a mess when dealing directly with a `contenteditable` element.

In my experiments I used to parse the innerHTML and replace some strings by their emoji unicode counterpart (eg: `'<3': '❤️'`), and used [Autolinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js/tree/master) library to replace found links by a link tag in my editable element.

`google.com --> <a href="https://www.google.com">google.com</a>`

**I want to avoid Quill toolbar and replace automatically emojis and links.**

So, I guess I have to replace editor's content at some place...

I'm really new to Quill, but I understand that it is working with a specific internal model called *deltas*, that allows [operational transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) (correct me if I'm wrong).

This assumption done, how would I check/parse these deltas and replace specific content in it in a way that preserves selection and caret position?

**References:**

https://quilljs.com/guides/designing-the-delta-format/

https://github.com/nadar/quill-delta-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Quill uses Delta to describe its contents. To get the current Deltas, you can use `quill.getContents`, and to set the new Deltas you can use `quill.setContents`.

To preserve the caret position you can use `getSelection` and `setSelection`.

However, the problem is that the [text-change](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#text-change) event happens after the DOM updates. Currently there are no really built-in such as `before-text-change`. This [similar Issue](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2558) has more details about problems modifying contents during `text-change` event. One way is to wrap the updates in `queueMicrotask`.

Here is a working example combining the methods mentioned above that replaces `<3` to `❤️` on text-change. You can extend it to replace other emojis and links, though it might have problems as said in the issue.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quill.on('text-change', update);

update(); //update for initial texts

function update(delta, oldContents, source) {
  if (source === 'silent') return;
  const newContents = quill.getContents()
    .map((op) => {
      if (typeof op.insert === 'string') {
        op.insert = op.insert.replaceAll('<3', '❤️');
      }
      return op;
    });

  queueMicrotask(() => {
    //getSelection be queued after DOM update to get copy-paste position updates  
    const selection = quill.getSelection();
    quill.setContents(newContents, 'silent');
    //don't set caret position if the editor wasn't focused before
    if (selection)
      quill.setSelection(selection.index, 0, 'silent');
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold <3 </strong> text <3 <3</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's huge! Thank you! Now I need to find a way to get selection after update when inserting eg. a three characters emoji like :-). I guess I need to get the difference between initial text length and subtract parsed text length to get the selection offset...

Comment: Thanks again, I actually managed to get a correct selection for all kind of emojis shortcuts (including eg `:joy:`) and to maintain a correct selection when setting bold or italic styles, by adding an offset variable that stores the difference between initial text length and parsed one, and setting `selection.length` in place of 0 in your call of `quill.setSelection`. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SyndRain answer, I finally learned about [Delta](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) and chosed to write a [Quill module](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/), to handle more edge cases.

It can be installed from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-emoji-parser) but for this answer, it's better to check the code on [Github](https://github.com/benoitlahoz/quill-emoji-parser). I explain what I learned below.

Regarding @SyndRain answer, the `queueMicrotask` hint is incredibly helpful: as far as I understand it, it gives time for Quill to render and change DOM before we update `selection` range.
To build the module, I based myself on the [quill-magic-url](https://github.com/visualjerk/quill-magic-url) code to handle both text change and paste events.

---

Emojis shortcuts can have very different length (ie. *:)* vs *:poop:*), and that was the problem to get correct caret position after parsing in my original question. Selection is only an issue when directly typing in the editor, so I wrote two different parsers.

Let's say we have a replacement map like below:

```
const map: Record<string, string> = {
  ':)': '',
}
```

**on `text-change`**

`this._quill.on('text-change', (delta) => { ... }`

1. Get last operation;
2. Save selection;
3. Get leaf text and its index;
4. Split text by space;
5. Loop on split text array to check if any word is a key in the emojis map.

If `true`, create a new `Delta` and update content:

```
const sel = this._quill.getSelection();
if (!sel) {
  return;
}

// Get the leaf and its index.
const [leaf] = this._quill.getLeaf(sel.index);
const leafIndex = this._quill.getIndex(leaf);

if (!leaf.text) {
  return;
}

// We only care about the leaf until the current cursor position.
const relevantLength = sel.index - leafIndex;
const text: string = leaf.text.slice(0, relevantLength);

if (!text) {
  return;
}

// ...
// Omitted for brevity: get each word by splicing text and test if word is in replacement map.
// ...

const ops = new Delta()
  // Retain text until the position of the word.
  .retain(leafIndex + text.indexOf(word))
  // Delete the word.
  .delete(word.length)
  // Insert the emoji.
  .insert(emoji);

// Update content now.
this._quill.updateContents(ops);

// Update selection when possible.
queueMicrotask(() => {
  this._quill.setSelection(
    // Set selection to the index of the original word + the emoji + space.
    leafIndex + text.indexOf(word) + emoji.length + 1,
    0,
    'silent'
  );
});
```

**on paste**

`this._quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.TEXT_NODE, (node: any, delta: typeof Delta) => { ... }`

1. It looks like pasted text is 'contained' in a single `Delta`;
2. So we can only check and replace shortcuts in the `insert` property of this delta;
3. We split the `insert` property text by space;
4. For each shortcut found we replace this `insert` by its replacement string, like in original answer (we could also use `replaceAll`).

```
op.insert = op.insert.replace(word, emoji);
```

A demo is available here: [quill-emoji-parser demo](https://benoitlahoz.github.io/quill-emoji-parser/)